# How to iterate through a list, element by element

Tags: list, loops, haskell, pattern-matching

I have just started learning Haskell and I am trying to write some basic functions in order to get a better understanding of this language.

I want to write a function which takes a list and an `Int` (`N`) as argument and returns the element at index `N` in the list, without using the `!!` operator or any built-in function.

Here is what I tried :

```
myHead :: [a] -> a
myHead (x:_) = x
myHead [] = error "head: empty list"

myNth :: [a] -> Int -> a
myNth x i = if i < 0
  then error "nth: index can't be negative"
  else myNthIterator x i 0

myNthIterator :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> a
myNthIterator [] i n = error "nth: bad index"
myNthIterator (_:x) i n = if i == n
  then myHead x
  else myNthIterator x i ( n + 1 )
```

It works but it's shifted to the right. For example `myNth [1, 2, 3, 4] 2` would give `4` and not `3`.

From what I understand, `(_:x)` removes the first element of the list and I don't see how to iterate through the list element by element.

Could someone put me on the trail? I find it difficult to find resources for beginners in this language.

Comment: `(_:x)` doesn't remove anything. It simply binds the name `x` to the tail of the argument, while ignoring the head.

Comment: By the time `i == n`, you *want* the value that `_` ignores. Your function would be correct if your condition were `i - 1 == n`, though that makes it difficult to get the 0th element. of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Maybe` to model whether the index was valid.

```hs
nth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth 0 (x : _) = Just x
nth n (x : xs) = nth (n - 1) xs
nth _ [] = Nothing
```

We can pattern match on the index to get our base case, and the list to get the first element and tail.

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I need. I will try to understand how this function works.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing there with `(_:x)` is called *"pattern matching"* in case you didn't know. The general pattern for iterating through a list would be `(x : xs)` where `x` is head element of the list being matched and `xs` is the rest of the list. If you use `_` you don't remove anything it is still matched to `_` which is the convention for saying "I won't use this".

With that you can make a function like this:

```
myNth :: [a] -> Int -> a
myNth  []      _ = error "out of range"
myNth (x : xs) 0 = x
myNth (_ : xs) n = myNth xs (n - 1)
```

Whenever `myNth` is called it will go top to bottom over those definitions trying to match the patterns to the input. So when you call `myNth [10,11] 1` it won't match the first clause because `[10,11]` doesn't match an empty list, it won't match the second either because `1` is not `0` and so it will match the third case where it will match the `[10,11]` on `(10 : [11])`, therefore `_` is `10` and `xs` is `[11]` and `1` will be matched as `n`. Then it calls itself recursively, as `myNth [11] 0`. Now *that* will match the second case and it will return `x` from the match of `[11]` on `(11 : [])`

Like 414owen said you can use the `Maybe a` type to avoid using `error`.

P.S.: I don't know how beginner you are but I assume you know of the `:` operator, it prepends an element to a list... If you go more in depth (afaik) every list is actually stored as a sequence of `a:(b:(c:(d:(e:[]))))` which is equivalent to `[a,b,c,d,e]` which is equivalent to `a:[b,c,d,e]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> It works but it's shifted to the right. For example `myNth [1, 2, 3, 4] 2` would give `4` and not `3`.

> ```
> myNthIterator (_:x) i n = if i == n
>   then myHead x
>   else myNthIterator x i ( n + 1 )
> ```

Let us look at `myNthIterator [1..4] 1 1`

```
myNthIterator [1..4] 1 1            -- replace [a, b] with (a: (b : []))
== myNthIterator (1 : [2, 3, 4]) 1 1
-- matching with `myNthIterator (_:x) i n` will result in
-- 1 ~ _
-- x ~ [2, 3, 4]
-- i ~ 1
-- n ~ 1
== if 1 == 1 then myHead [2, 3, 4] else myNthIterator [2, 3, 4] 1 (1 + 1)
== myHead [2, 3, 4]
== 2
```

So `(_:x)` matching against `(1 : [2, 3, 4])` is suspicious. A first step in fixing it is to replace `(_:x)` by `(x:xs)`.

```
myNthIterator (x:xs) i n = ...
```

In our example this would mean `x == 1` and `xs == [2, 3, 4]`.